# Should I eliminate a predictor with big p value from the final model?

Tags: predictive-models

I developed a prediction model using stepAIC after univariate analysis.
glm(formula = outcome_m6 ~ age.x + lesion_size + index_cat.x + pain.x, family = binomial, data = data)
The following is the summary info of the model.
Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)      2.7372   587.8717   0.005  0.99628
lesion_size.L  -14.2324  1247.0614  -0.011  0.99089
lesion_size.Q    7.3856   719.9912   0.010  0.99182
index_cat.x1     2.4286     1.2482   1.946  0.05169 .
pain.x1          2.2450     0.7021   3.197  0.00139 **
age.x.L          0.8547     0.4451   1.920  0.05483 .

Lesion size has quite high p value and only one of the coefficients are negative.
Should I eliminate lesion_size from the model because of the high pvalue? when univariate analysis, this predictor has smallest p value, so I am a bit confused.

ROC and calibration shows the good model performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Don't remove variables based on p-values.
Here is a prior question with several answers that explain why...

[Algorithms for automatic model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection)